# Mongoose findOneAndReplace replacement doc empty

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to replace a document in one of my models(configurations) and for that I am using [findOneAndReplace](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findOneAndReplace) method.
However, mongoose replaces the document with an empty one.

I invoke the method as:

```
let updateData = { _id: '5ecba01dbac0c68120535f40', data: 'newData' };

Configuration.findOneAndReplace({ uuid : req.params.uid }, updateData, (err, conf) => {
    if ( err ) {
        sendErrorResponse ( res, err );
    } else {
        res.json ( {
            status : 1,
            data   : conf
        } );
    }
} );
```

In the logs, I can see this:

```
configurations.findOneAndReplace({ uuid: 'default' }, {}, { _id: '5ecba01dbac0c68120535f40', data: 'newData' }, projection: {}})
```

As per the documentation, the second parameter should be the replacement document but mongoose is passing the replacement document as 3rd parameter and second parameter is empty. I think that's the reason that it sets it empty in the db.

Now instead of this, if I use [findOneAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate), it works completely fine. I get the following in the logs:

```
configurations.findOneAndUpdate({ uuid: 'default' }, { '$set': { _id: '5ecba01dbac0c68120535f40', data: 'newData' }}, { upsert: false, projection: {}, returnOriginal: true })
```

But I want to replace the document instead of updating it. Is there something that I am missing or is this probably a bug in mongoose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've had a similar issue recently - setting the options to a an empty object and enabling `useFindAndModify` in the connection settings resolved the issue for us:

```
// connection-setup

mongoose.connect('mongodb://...', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useFindAndModify:true });

// findOneAndReplace call

Configuration.findOneAndReplace({ uuid : req.params.uid }, updateData, {}, (err, conf) => {
        ...
});
```

Also there's this github [issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/7654) which might be of help.